# Pasar datos desde js a una vista en django

Tags: javascript, django, script, views

Hola todos he pensado guardar en una variable en javascript un dato y luego enviarlo a una vista de django para usar ese dato, en este caso la variable formatSelected, aclaro q el codigo de javascript está en un template de django, O que opciones tengo para lograrlo?

***Script de javascript***

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".formato-button").on("click", function() {
      const formatSelected = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".formato-title").text();
      let height = 0;
      let width = 0;
      if (formatSelected == "A4") {
        width = 2480;
        height = 3508;
      } else if (formatSelected == "Facebook") {
        width = 1200;
        height = 630;
      } else if (formatSelected == "Instagram") {
        width = 1080;
        height = 1080;
      }
      localStorage.setItem("width", width);
      localStorage.setItem("height", height);
    })
  });
```

***vista django***

```
class FondoView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'fondo.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        all_records = Image.objects.filter(format="variable javascript")
        filtered_records = None
        filter_category = int(self.request.GET.get('search_tipo')) if self.request.GET.get('search_tipo') else 1
        filter_name = self.request.GET.get('search_fondo')
        if (not filter_category and not filter_name):
            image_json = serializers.serialize('json', all_records)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar una variable desde javascript puedes utilizar una petición fetch y enviar por método post la variable, por ejemplo:

```
var myFormatSelected = 'dato';
fetch('/your_url/',{
     method: 'POST,
     headers: {'Content-Type': 'applicatiom/json'},
     body: JSON.stringify({formatSelected: myFormatSelected})
})
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Luego en tu views.py:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_var = request.POST.get('formatSelected')
        print(my_var)
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'ok'})
```

Comment: Gracias Kenner lo usare asi. miro como me va. aunque me habian comentado de guardarlo como cookie

Comment: Sí, puedes guardarlo como una Cookie y enviarlo. 
Yo por ejemplo utilizo una cookie para almacenar el token de un usuario y lo mando por fetch cada vez que necesite hacer una petición.